# Tukey Kramer and the reduction of type one error

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-error, type-i-and-ii-errors, tukey-hsd-test

I hope everyone is doing well. I understand that the Tukey Kramer reduces the chance of getting a type 1 error by using a pooled variance. That pooled variance then gives you a lower standard error than a regular T Test. However, when calculating your Q - Stat wouldnt a lower standard error cause a your result to be farther away than a higher standard error of the T test? Because the formula is Ya - Yb/SE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare the two statistics directly. The $t$-statistic is compared against the quantile of a $t$-distribution, while the statistic of the Tukey-Kramer is compared against the quantile of a studentized range distribution.